# Infinite Scroll won't load more posts on scroll down when included in another file with HTML tags on top of it

Tags: javascript, php

I have an Infinite Scroll that loads more data (from DB) upon scrolling to the bottom,

However, when I try to include that file in another .PHP file and write any HTML tag at its top, it won't load more posts.

On console, I get an error as

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

```
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (test.php:126)
at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)`
```

My code goes as :

**getData.php**

```
<?php

require_once('db.php');

if (! function_exists('getData')) {
    /**
     * @param int $offset
     * @param int $limit
     * @return array|null
     */
    
    function getData($offset, $limit, $conn) {
        $offset = (int)$offset;
        $limit  = (int)$limit;
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery);
        $rows = [];
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $cleanRow = [];
            foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
                $cleanRow[$column] = htmlentities($value);
            }
            $rows[]= $cleanRow;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
require_once ('getData.php');

$offset = (int)($_GET['offset'] ?? 0);
$dataOnly = (int)($_GET['dataOnly'] ?? 0);
$limit  = 7;
$rows = getData($offset, $limit, $conn);
$offset+= $limit;
$data = [
    'rows'   => $rows,
    'offset' => $offset,
];


$data = json_encode($data);

// if this is an ajax call, stop here and just spit out our json
if ($dataOnly) {
    echo $data;
    exit;
}
// otherwise, render the page
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_posts";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery);
$total_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            background: #e9ebee;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }

        .post-wall {
            background: #FFF;
            border: #e0dfdf 1px solid;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 500px;
        }

        .post-item {
            padding: 10px;
            border: #f3f3f3 1px solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .post-title {
            color: #4faae6;
        }

        .ajax-loader {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .ajax-loader img {
            width: 50px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
<div class="post-wall">
    <div id="post-list">
        <input type="hidden" name="total_count" id="total_count" value="<?= $total_count ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="offset" id="offset" value="<?= $offset ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="ajax-loader text-center">
        <img src="LoaderIcon.gif"> Loading more posts...
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // load the initial rows on page load
        let initialData = <?= $data ?? '' ?>;
        if (initialData) {
            if (initialData.rows) {
                addrows(initialData.rows);
                $('.ajax-loader').hide();
            }
        }
        windowOnScroll();

    });
    function windowOnScroll() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + 1 >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        if ($(".post-item").length < $("#total_count").val()) {
          let offset = $('#offset').val();
          getMoreData(offset)
        }
      }
    });
  }

    function getMoreData(offset) {
        $('.ajax-loader').show();
        $(window).off("scroll");
        let pageUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
        $.ajax({
            url: pageUrl + '?dataOnly=1&offset=' + offset,
            type: "get",
            
            success: function (response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            if (response.rows) {
            addrows(response.rows);
            if (response.offset) {
            $('#offset').val(response.offset);
            }
            $('.ajax-loader').hide();
            }
            windowOnScroll();
            }
        });
    }

    function addrows(rows) {
        let postList = $("#post-list");
        $.each(rows, function (i, row) {
            let rowHtml = '<div class="post-item" id="'+row.id+'"><p class="post-title">'+row.title+'</p><p>'+row.content+'</p></div>';
            postList.append(rowHtml);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Now please note that the above code works completely fine, as infinite scroll does exactly what it needs to be.
But when I place it inside another file like

**test.php**

```
<div>
<?php include("index.php"); ?>
</div>
```

the first few posts (7) load and along with the loader.gif at the bottom. That's all.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any js errors? Also are you sure getMoreData method is called, my advice - put console.log(offset) right after function getMoreData(offset) { ... and see in debugger if you get anything at all.

Comment: @AngelDeykov So i added the console.log after getMoreData, the console have the same JQuery error while in network upon clicking on `test.php?dataOnly=1&offset=7` I get the data from table in response

Comment: So you're getting the data you need, it's just not shown on the page ? Is function addrows(rows)  being executed ?

Comment: Move $('.ajax-loader').hide(); at the beginning of function addrows(rows) { and see if loader will hide, also you will know if method is properly called

Comment: Moved the ajax-loader to `function addrows(rows) {
        $('.ajax-loader').hide();` but the loader still shows up at the bottom

Comment: You see the logic now, if you don't have js errors is to use console.log() to track how code is being executed, so you know if you have success: with your ajax call, check "where your code goes", cause I see you have some if statements - if (response.rows) { for example, is this check OK, does your code goes to addrows()?

Comment: so it means this method is not being executed

Comment: put console.log('test') right after success: function (response) {... and see in debugger if you get it

Comment: Yes, i see the test in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223004/discussion-between-harry-k-and-angel-deykov).

Comment: so you have success call, good :) Now put console.log('test 1') after if (response.rows) { ... console.log('test 2') after if (response.offset) {... and  right before you call windowOnScroll(); --- } console.log('test 3')  windowOnScroll(); and see where you get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After basic understanding on what the error is trying to say, I finally figured out this as

ERROR:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (test.php:126)
at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

JSON should start with a valid JSON value – an object, array, string, number, or false/true/null. This response started with a < (hence the “Unexpected token <”).

That unexpected token, <, is a strong clue that the response was HTML instead of JSON.

The root cause is that the server returned HTML or some other non-JSON string.

So what I did was, just simply cut the JSON code into the top of the test.php leaving everything as it is.

**index.php**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            background: #e9ebee;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }

        .post-wall {
            background: #FFF;
            border: #e0dfdf 1px solid;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 500px;
        }

        .post-item {
            padding: 10px;
            border: #f3f3f3 1px solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .post-title {
            color: #4faae6;
        }

        .ajax-loader {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .ajax-loader img {
            width: 50px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
<div class="post-wall">
    <div id="post-list">
        <input type="hidden" name="total_count" id="total_count" value="<?= $total_count ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="offset" id="offset" value="<?= $offset ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="ajax-loader text-center">
        <img src="LoaderIcon.gif"> Loading more posts...
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // load the initial rows on page load
        let initialData = <?= $data ?? '' ?>;
        if (initialData) {
            if (initialData.rows) {
                addrows(initialData.rows);
                $('.ajax-loader').hide();
            }
        }
        windowOnScroll();

    });
    function windowOnScroll() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + 1 >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        if ($(".post-item").length < $("#total_count").val()) {
          let offset = $('#offset').val();
          getMoreData(offset)
        }
      }
    });
  }

    function getMoreData(offset) {
        $('.ajax-loader').show();
        $(window).off("scroll");
        let pageUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
        $.ajax({
            url: pageUrl + '?dataOnly=1&offset=' + offset,
            type: "get",
            
            success: function (response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            if (response.rows) {
            addrows(response.rows);
            if (response.offset) {
            $('#offset').val(response.offset);
            }
            $('.ajax-loader').hide();
            }
            windowOnScroll();
            }
        });
    }

    function addrows(rows) {
        let postList = $("#post-list");
        $.each(rows, function (i, row) {
            let rowHtml = '<div class="post-item" id="'+row.id+'"><p class="post-title">'+row.title+'</p><p>'+row.content+'</p></div>';
            postList.append(rowHtml);
        });
    }
</script>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
require_once ('getData.php');

$offset = (int)($_GET['offset'] ?? 0);
$dataOnly = (int)($_GET['dataOnly'] ?? 0);
$limit  = 7;
$rows = getData($offset, $limit, $conn);
$offset+= $limit;
$data = [
    'rows'   => $rows,
    'offset' => $offset,
];


$data = json_encode($data);

// if this is an ajax call, stop here and just spit out our json
if ($dataOnly) {
    echo $data;
    exit;
}
// otherwise, render the page
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_posts";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery);
$total_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>

<div class="some">
<?PHP include("index.php"); ?>
</div>
```

And Voila. It works perfectly fine.

**Thanks to @WesleySmith & @AngelDeykov** for the time they spared on this.